# Caffeine 2.8.3 Doesn't Keep Screen Awake (ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04

I installed caffeine using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

I have the icon in the top tray, and it's activated, however it still turns off the screen after about 1 or 2 minutes.

This should be the right version, and I followed [This tutorial](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-caffeine-indicator-ubuntu-14-04/) on how to install it exactly, did I do something wrong?

Comment: What tutorial did you follow? can you add the link to the tutorial in the question?

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/01/install-caffeine-indicator-ubuntu-14-04/